# How to extend multilevel columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a df with two level columns

```
      a                                                
  E1_g1 E1_g2 E1_g3 E2_g1 E2_g2 E2_g3 E3_g1 E3_g2 E3_g3
0     4     0     3     3     3     1     3     2     4
1     0     0     4     2     1     0     1     1     0
```

From a list `tuple`

```
[('a', 'E1', 'g1'), ('a', 'E1', 'g2'), ('a', 'E1', 'g3'), ('a', 'E2', 'g1'), ('a', 'E2', 'g2'), ('a', 'E2', 'g3'), ('a', 'E3', 'g1'), ('a', 'E3', 'g2'), ('a', 'E3', 'g3')]
```

The list of `tuple` is generated from `for-loop` shown in accompanying code below.

I would like to expand it into 3 level from the given list tuple

```
   a                        
  E1       E2       E3      
  g1 g2 g3 g1 g2 g3 g1 g2 g3
0  4  0  3  3  3  1  3  2  4
1  0  0  4  2  1  0  1  1  0
```

I have the impression this simply can be achieve via

```
df.colums=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ntuple)
```

However,applying the above produce

```
      a                                                
  E1_g1 E1_g2 E1_g3 E2_g1 E2_g2 E2_g3 E3_g1 E3_g2 E3_g3
0     4     0     3     3     3     1     3     2     4
1     0     0     4     2     1     0     1     1     0
```

May I know what am I missing here?

The full code to reproduce the above is below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 9))

_names = ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a']
_idx = ['E1_g1','E1_g2','E1_g3',
        'E2_g1','E2_g2','E2_g3',
        'E3_g1','E3_g2','E3_g3']
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([_names, _idx])

df= pd.DataFrame(data=arr, columns=columns)

ntuple=[]
for dg in df.columns:
    A,B=dg
    f,r=B.split('_')
    ntuple.append((A,f,r))


df.colums=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ntuple)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the list of tuples, you can use `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`:

```py
tuples = [('a', 'E1', 'g1'), ('a', 'E1', 'g2'), ('a', 'E1', 'g3'), ('a', 'E2', 'g1'), ('a', 'E2', 'g2'), ('a', 'E2', 'g3'), ('a', 'E3', 'g1'), ('a', 'E3', 'g2'), ('a', 'E3', 'g3')]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
```

Output:

```
   a                        
  E1       E2       E3      
  g1 g2 g3 g1 g2 g3 g1 g2 g3
0  4  0  3  3  3  1  3  2  4
1  0  0  4  2  1  0  1  1  0
```

---

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 9))
tuples = [('a', 'E1', 'g1'), ('a', 'E1', 'g2'), ('a', 'E1', 'g3'), ('a', 'E2', 'g1'), ('a', 'E2', 'g2'), ('a', 'E2', 'g3'), ('a', 'E3', 'g1'), ('a', 'E3', 'g2'), ('a', 'E3', 'g3')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
```

---

For using `_names` and `_idx`:

```py
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([[name]+idx.split('_') for name,idx in zip(_names,_idx)])
```

Comment: But, my list of tuples is the `ntuple` itself

Comment: It's working here. I saw you updated your question, could you use `df.columns` instead of `df.colums` and post the updated print? Also, can you try out the last line of this answer?

Comment: Thanks for the interest @Caina. Sorry for the lack of info provided. Actually, I need to use the tuple that being created with the `for loops` as in original implementation, there are some columns that being drop. In the same vein, I am unable to utilise your second alternative.

Comment: But, the `ntuple` itself is a list of tuple and is similar to your `tuple`. But, I am curios why I cannot simply `df.colums=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ntuple)`